How to interpret two-way anova results?
Currently working on my thesis about the effect of the combination of FA and CCR on the strength of soil. The p-values from the two-way ANOVA for the two main factors and their interaction are statistically significant (< 0.05). What does this imply? Are there any statistical analysis tests, like post hoc tests, that I need to conduct further?

Yes. ANOVA tests if there is a "significant difference" between the values of variables and post hoc tests are designed to tell you what and where is that "significant difference" in the variables.

Welcome to CV.  If you click on the tag that is on your question, you will find extensive discussion of all sorts of questions about ANOVA.
Very briefly, though:
The fact that the main effects and the interaction are significant means that, if there were no differences in the population from which your sample was randomly drawn, you would be unlikely to get test statistics as extreme as the ones you got.
The interaction means that the relation between each independent variable and the DV is different at different levels of the other IV.
And there are post hoc tests you can do to find out more, but these are not required, though they can be interesting in many situations.

Maybe the easiest way to interpret a 2-way ANOVA (for that matter any ANOVA) is to realize that an ANOVA is fundamentally a linear regression. Thus, a significant p-value for the ANOVA means that there is some linear relationship between the DV and the IV's. Now, as the ANOVA test is an omnibus test, i.e. an overall or global test it just tells you that there is "some kind" of linear relationship, but it does not really tell you what that relationship is.
For that, you need to look at the p-values for the different factors (your software should also produce these?). In your case, you tested for the 2 primary IV's, and their interaction term. All 3 of them could be significant, or 2, or only 1. Your software may also produce a "main effects plot" and an "interaction" plot, which would tell you which terms are significant. The 2 IV terms are simple to interpret; they both can influence the DV linearly, and if both are significant, they work additively (or subtractively, depending on the sign of the linear coefficient; they may not work in the same direction, but they still compound additively). If the interaction term is significant, it means that the 2 IV's work multiplicatively, i.e. the effect of one factor depends on the level of the other(s).
Now, again depending on your software, you may/should get an optimizing answer, that is the optimum levels of the various factors which would maximize/minimize the DV.
